# Why am I getting an error when I attempt to convert a double to a float?

Tags: c#

I have a little problem converting a double to a float. Code:

```
float volume = 0.5;
Double i = Volume.Value;
volume = (float)i / 100F;
Bass.BASS_SetVolume(volume);
```

As you can see I'm using the BASS library. Volume is a slider that gives me a value from 1 to 100. The problem is, I'm getting this error:

> error CS0664: Literal of type double cannot be implicitly converted to type 'float'; use an 'F' suffix to create a literal of this type

Why do I get this error?

Comment: `volume` was defined as a `double`. It doesn't matter that you "put in" a float, it will be converted back to a `double` (implicitly).

Comment: volume is defined as float. Even without "/ 100F" it gives me same error message.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
float volume = 0.5;
```

This line will give you your error.  Floating points are `double` by default, hence it can't implicitly convert `0.5` into a float.  Try using `0.5f` instead.

Comment: This looks like it is the solution to the issue.

Comment: +1 This is correct. OP omitted this line originally as well as information on which line caused the error.